# Determine income tax

Tags: taxes, usa

As a freelancer, how do I determine how much federal withholding I should pay? I've been paying estimated taxes for 2014, but that did not include **income tax** so now I'm facing a hefty bill. I would like to avoid this situation for next year.

Comment: Where do you live? Have you looked at your local tax revenue service's website?

Comment: My state does not have an income tax, so I am not sure how my local tax revenue service's website would help.

Comment: Surely you're paying income tax to someone? By local I meant your country's tax website.

Comment: Paying quarterly estimates **is** paying income tax. What have you been paying if not estimated quarterly taxes?

Comment: @Scott I thought my estimated taxes was just the medicare and social security taxes.

Comment: Estimated taxes, at least for me, are based on an estimate of what I will earn in the coming year and how much total income tax will need to be paid. They don't separate out specific taxes. It's essentially an escrow account for your coming tax bill, all of it, not just specific taxes. You should speak to a tax professional.

Answer (score 4):

Run, don't walk, to a local certified accountant.  You need advice from a professional in this area.  Time is running out on your 2014 taxes.  The financial penalties can be significant if you have mis-estimated your tax liability.